# How to show label as it is in the data?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, label

I am plotting a graph between `time` and `value`. I want these `time` label to be shown as `2018-06-30 18:35:45` as in the main csv data.

Instead the graph on x axis shows `time` as `06:30 20`.

How can the labels of x axis can be exact as mentioned in the main data.

Code I used is:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

 df = pd.read_csv('Mlogi_ALL_idle_day.csv')

 df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ns')

 x = df['time']
 y = df['d']

 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
 ax.plot_date(x, y, linestyle='-')
 plt.title('Idle for 1 July - 2 July 2018')
 plt.legend()
 plt.ylabel('duration')
 plt.xlabel('Time')
 fig.autofmt_xdate()
 plt.show()
```

And the data look like:

```
 In[10]:df.head()
 Out[10]: 
             time            d
 0 2018-06-30 18:35:45  41000000000
 1 2018-06-30 18:36:47  44000000000
 2 2018-06-30 18:37:46  43000000000
 3 2018-06-30 18:38:46  40000000000
 4 2018-06-30 18:39:47  43000000000
```

Comment: If you want to show a label at 18:35:45, what makes this different from 18:35:47? Or do you also want to show a label for 18:35:47? But then they would overlap because those times are too close and hence be unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the date label of the major x-axis tick you can use

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```